# Chrome log-in error when attempting access to localhost webapp

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

I am new to web/MySQL apps and have come across a problem trying to log into my Web Pro Manager page on both IE 10 and Chrome. Getting a *login failed* error on both browsers.

Does DCOM or cookies have anything to do with this login failure? I tried incognito mode – still the same. I also noticed a login failure with other web apps.

I have cookies enabled, no success.

Running Windows 8 Professional, 64-bit. I have Norton Antivirus, PHP 5.4, Apache 2.4 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Web Pro Manager uses session cookies to keep you logged in like most web-based administration systems.  Your browser must accept cookies to maintain your login.  If you're having trouble logging in to Web Pro Manager as well as other web apps, try making sure your browser is accepting cookies.  [This link](http://www.whatarecookies.com/enable.asp) may help depending on you browser.